# File counting with Powershell commands

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I count all files in a specific folder (and all subfolders) with the **Powershell** command Get-ChildItem?
With `(Get-ChildItem <Folder> -recurse).Count` also the folders are counted and this is not that what I want. Are there other possibilities for counting files in very big folders quickly?

Does anybody know a short and good tutorial regarding the Windows Powerhell?

Comment: for the tutorial you can start from here: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/

Answer (score 19):

I would pipe the result to the `Measure-Object` cmdlet. Using (...).Count can yield nothing in case there are no objects that match your criteria.

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem <Folder> -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object
 $files.Count
```

In PowerShell v3 we can do the following to get files only:

```
 Get-ChildItem <Folder> -File -Recurse
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter for files before counting:

```
(Get-ChildItem <Folder> -recurse | where-object {-not ($_.PSIsContainer)}).Count
```